# Ionic javascript data-dismiss bootstrap modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

I'm trying to write a function in JavaScript that opens an model when a player enters a certain box. The model does pop up, but it no longer closes.

This is used to open the model :

The JavaScript:

```
superFight(){
function ModalLink(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}

ModalLink();
}
```

The HTML Model:

```
<div id="myModal" class="" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Modaldd Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I already tried to use `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` and `$('#myModal').modal({ show: false});`

This did not work. When I put it in the console, it gave :

```
> $('#myModal').modal({ show: false});
< false = $1
```

I also tried an onClick function in the close button to activate a function to close the modal, but this not work either.

Basically what I'm trying to do, is to open and close an modal programmatically. Whenever an superFight(); is started, it should pop up with some info. And the user should be able to close it when done.

I'm writing the code in an ionic app.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I changed the code in `superFight()` to:

```
function superFight(){
  $('#myModal').show();
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  $( ".simplemodal-overlay" ).show();
}
```

Added an onClick the HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="CloseModalSpel()">&times;</button>
```

And then in the page, I added this function at the bottom:

```
function CloseModalSpel(){
  $('#myModal').hide();
  $( ".simplemodal-overlay" ).hide();
}
```

It now opens, and closes the modal.